# Memcached not working beyond scope(?)

Tags: python, django, caching, scope, memcached

I cannot seem to find any instances of memcached seemingly having some sort of scope, but that is what seems to be happening to me right now.

In my `views.py`, I have a value stored in memcached auto increment every time the page loads. I know this is working because after about 30 reloads, it is at about 30.

However, if I try to access this variable from `python manage.py shell`, for example, the value stored there does not work. Furthermore, any values I store in that shell will persist only while that shell is running.

Here is what I am doing in the shell:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.cache import cache

> cache.get('my_incr_key') # This auto-increments in views.py
None
> cache.get('my_new_key')
None
> cache.set('my_new_key', 12, None)
> cache.get('my_new_key')
12
```

The problem is, if I exit the shell, then run this again, the same exact thing will happen: most notably, getting `my_new_key` will still return `None`. That I cannot see the value stored in `my_incr_key` suggests to me that there is a scope issue at play.

This is driving me absolutely nuts!

Is there such a thing as scope for `memcached`? Is that what is at play here? How can I fix this 'scope' issue?

If possible, I would like to only use memcached and not have to deal with any files.

**Edit**

This is what I have added to `settings.py`:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

How do I indicate that this is the cache that I want to use when I import `cache` from `django.core.cache`?

Comment: You're sure you're not using local memory cache? Can you show the CACHES section of your settings?

Comment: @IainShelvington, oddly enough there is *nothing* with "CACH" in it in my `settings.py` at all, yet the cache seems to be working for `views.py`

Comment: You need to specify memcached in your settings -
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#memcached. The default cache setting uses local memory cache which only exists within the running process

Comment: You can test this by restarting your server. Your cache will be "reset" if you are running local memory caching

Comment: @IainShelvington, so that means that that memory is inaccessible to other processes like the manage.py shell?

Comment: Yes, because it's local memory. To make things available to other processes, you use a shared process, which is exactly what memcached is.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, and also does it matter what the location is so long as it is consistent? I am running this Django project with Apache 2.

Comment: I don't understand either question. You've set the cache backend to memcached, so Django will now use it. And the location needs to be set to wherever memcached is actually running.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, sorry memcached and django are pretty new to me. Should the location where memcache is run be different if I am using Apache 2 as opposed to a localhost development server?

Comment: Memcached is completely separate from Django and does not use either Apache or the dev server. It is its own server which runs according to its own configuration.